# Clarification about Vue Reactivity System

Tags: vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I always wanted to ask the following questions regarding the Vue Reactivity System.

I have read in Vue docs that it is recommended to keep the data of components as plain JS objects over being class objects. Same goes for individual properties of components data.

Why is this recommendation?
What is the problem with having data as instances of class objects?
What edge cases are caused by using getters/setters and methods inside of component data? (this is my main question here)

I have also another question about Vue Reactivity System.

Can I directly change component computed getters/setters and methods at runtime without having problems with Vue Reactivity System?
Are changed computed getters/setters still be cached and optimized?
Are changed methods going to be accessible from component template?
Can I add new computed getters/setters and methods at runtime? How?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Vue reactivity system (but i suppose i can extend it to all other reactive framework/lib/whatever) is just an implementation of the [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) . In the specific case, the observer function is fired when a property value (data, computed getter result, vuex state) changes. if the property is an integer and its value is 2, is easy for vue to check out that at some point of time it has become '3', after a comparison, fired with a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html), a [vdom change](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) etc...and this is same for other primitive types. When structured object come into play, the comparison between values is still made, but this time the value will be a reference to the object. If the reference doesn't change, vue cannot know that something has changed, so just doesn't react....

if you set val [3](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)  = 'foo' before and val [3](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)  = 'bar' after, the 'val' array is still the same object in the same heap area, so you should clone it, or better use [Vue.set()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Comment: What about my questions?